# Why isn't the parameter getting passed to my route

Tags: laravel

I must have missed something...wondering why the parameter isn't getting passed into my route.

My URL ends up looking like
    `//admin/attendees/%7Battendee%7D/paid`
I want the `%7Battendees%7D` to be replaced with a number

Here's my route and view

```
Route::post('attendees/{attendee}/paid', array('as' =>'admin.attendees.paid', 'uses'=>'AdminAttendeeController@postPaid'));

{{Form::open(array('class' => 'paid', 'method'  =>  'POST', 'route' => 'admin.attendees.paid', $attendee->id))}}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```blade
{{ 
    Form::open(array(
        'class' => 'paid', 
        'method' => 'POST', 
        'route' => array('admin.attendees.paid', $attendee->id)
    )) 
}}
```

You can find more details in illuminate/html source code: https://github.com/illuminate/html/blob/master/FormBuilder.php#L799

Comment: Thanks! I see I forgot to use an array for route parameters :D